# The meaning of "account for" in a specific context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, synonyms, phrasal-verbs

A colleague of mine wrote something today that is still boggling my mind.

> Os delays video when a headset is present to account for the latency

Is "account for" the synonym for "take into account" here? All the dictionaries I checked don't list it as a synonym therefore I am a bit confused if that is an incorrect use of "account for" or I am missing something.

Comment: *As an explanation of* is the read you should take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definition 4 in this [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/account%20for%20%28something%29) definition:

> US : to think about (something) before doing something : to take (something) into consideration
> *The researchers failed to account for the fact that most of the students were poor.*